# Trying to Return an Input from a Dropdown Menu to a Variable in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing one of my first programs, and I can't figure out how to fix this issue.  I started learning Python like a week ago and am still very new to Tkinter and OOP in general.  I got this script (D&D NPC Generator) working without using OOP, but I wanted to see how to do it with OOP since that's how most people seem to prefer using Tkinter.

Here's the code for the Input window:

```
class Input:

    def __init__(self, master):

        ideals = ["Good", "Evil",
                  "Lawful", "Chaotic",
                  "Neutral", "Other"]

        ideal_selection = StringVar()
        ideal_selection.set(ideals[0])

        self.name_label = Label(master, text="NPC Name: ")
        self.name_entry = Entry(master)

        self.ideal_label = Label(master, text="Ideal Type: ")
        self.ideal_entry = OptionMenu(master, ideal_selection, *ideals)

        self.submit_button = Button(text="Submit", command=self.close_window)

        self.name_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.ideal_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.submit_button.grid(columnspan=2, row=3, column=0)

        self.ideal_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def close_window(self):
        global name
        global ideal_type
        name = self.name_entry.get()
        ideal_type = self.ideal_selection.get()
        self.master.destroy()
```

And it's returning:

```
AttributeError: 'Input' object has no attribute 'ideal_selection'
```

I have no idea what's going wrong.  My goal with this GUI window is to have the user type in a name for the NPC and then select an option from a drowbown menu for what kind of ideal the user wants the NPC to have.  A fix and explanation of what I did wrong would be very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `ideal_selection` as a local variable and not a class instance variable.
Therefore, calling `self.ideal_selection.get()` will fail as there is no `self` to reference.

You need to change the declaration from: `ideal_selection = StringVar()` to: `this.ideal_selection = StringVar()` and change all other references over to `this.ideal_selection`.

Note that you have done this for everything else (`self.name_entry`) ...

Afterword:

I'd like to discourage you from your use of `global` here. When you have tkinter running under OOP principles, you can return values from your class back to the calling script.

(Note also eventually I would recommend not using `from tkinter import *`).

Have a look at what happens if your code is amended to:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
import sys

class Input(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        ideals = ["Good", "Evil",
                  "Lawful", "Chaotic",
                  "Neutral", "Other"]

        self.ideal_selection = tk.StringVar()
        self.ideal_selection.set(ideals[0])

        self.name_label = tk.Label(root, text="NPC Name: ")
        self.name_entry = tk.Entry(root)

        self.ideal_label = tk.Label(root, text="Ideal Type: ")
        self.ideal_entry = tk.OptionMenu(root, self.ideal_selection, *ideals)

        self.submit_button = tk.Button(text="Submit", command=self.close_window)

        self.name_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.ideal_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.submit_button.grid(columnspan=2, row=3, column=0)

        self.ideal_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def close_window(self):
        #global name
        #global ideal_type
        self.name = self.name_entry.get()
        self.ideal_type = self.ideal_selection.get()
        #self.destroy()
        self.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("600x400+300+300")
    app = Input(root)
    root.mainloop()
    # Note the returned variables here
    # They must be assigned to external variables
    # for continued use
    returned_name = app.name
    returned_ideal = app.ideal_type
    print("Your name is: " + returned_name)
    print("Your ideal is: " + returned_ideal)
    # Should only need root.destroy() to close down tkinter
    # But need to handle user cancelling the form instead
    try:
        root.destroy()
    except:
        sys.exit(1)
```